# Google App Engine instances stop responding

Tags: google-app-engine

This started happening about 2 weeks ago. I have 2 websites hosted on App Engine. All of a sudden both started showing blank screens on every request. Both had instances running and there were no errors in the logs.

After some trial an error I found that running the deployment (appcfg update) fixes this problem, but only for an hour or so. My colleague also found out that shutting down running instances also gets rid of the blank screen and also for a limited time.

The period during which site remains functional varies from 10 mins to 2 hours. The the blank screen. The logs either show no errors or keep loading forever showing nothing at all.

At the moment I have 2 tasks in scheduled to run every 10 minutes that start deployment scripts for every site. Again, this started happening on 2 sites at the same time and both sites haven't been updated in a while, nor have I changed any app engine related settings for them.

Comment: So, if not errors, what DO the app engine logs show for attempts to visit a website that result in a blank screen?  Any other info you can share?  Hard to offer any help  based on this scarce information...

Comment: Do the blank screen requests show up in logs?  What response code to they return?

Comment: Just tried on the smaller site. Got blank screen after 33 minutes, The instances page shows one instance currently running and served 43 requests. The number of requests increases as I refresh the sites homepage. so the instance is alive in some way.

When I got to the logs page for that instance it says "Loading..." for a very long time, then briefly shows "No entries found" and shows "Loading" placeholder again. I do no even see requests made before the site became blank.

Answer (score 0):

Which scaling method you are using for your application ? If you are not sure, then go through the link [1] to understand how to configure scaling in your application . I have a suspicion that ue to scaling issue the instance is unable to response.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class